# Constructing a specific context free grammar

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

$\Sigma=\{a,b\}$
L = {w| |w| is a multiple of 4 and b is in the first quarter of w}

I need to find construct a CFG for L, but my partner and I have been struggling with this for several hours to no avail.

If we have a start symbol S, my thought would be to somehow divide S into parts, possible into a first quarter and the last three quarters,
ie

$S \rightarrow XY$ where X contains b and Y has three times the length of X.
The problem is there is no way to allow for recursivity while implementing this length relation of X and Y.

Any ideas?

Comment: **Hint.** $S\to TSTTT$, where $T$ is any single symbol, will get you some of the way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm This makes sense, except that we must have that in at least one of the iterations of this, the first T must be a B, which is an issue

Comment: " X contains b" Is it all b's or at least one b ?

Comment: at least one b, sorry for any ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a solution due to some of your ideas

$S \rightarrow TSTTT | bXTTT | \varepsilon$

$X \rightarrow TXTTT | \varepsilon$

$T \rightarrow a|b$

Comment: That almost works -- except $S\to\varepsilon$ shouldn't be there; it would allow you to derive $\mathtt{aaaa}$. By the way, tou could avoid the $X$ by saying $$ S \to \mathtt aSTTT \mid \mathtt bTTT \mid STTTT $$ but it's somewhat more involved to convince oneself that works.